# iPhone 4 as webcam for Mac

Tags: iphone, webcam

I'm searching for an app and software to to let me use my iPhone 4 as a webcam for MSN and others. My phone is 4.0.1 and jailbroken. I'm using Mac OS X 10.6.4.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](http://www.drahtwerk.biz/EN/Products/iPhone/iWebcamera/Drivers.aspx) a link to iWebCamera for Mac. Let me know how that works!